# QLPreviewController play item

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

If we have a `QLPreviewController` with video file inside, the video is loaded is a `paused` state. The user has to tap on `play` icon to make it play. I can't find any (legal) programmatic way to play the video, is there anything?

Answer (score 1):

There is no public API for this (according to documentation).

There is workaround with private API usage, but in this case app can be rejected by Apple:

Iterate through subviews in `QLPreviewController`, find "play" button, and tap on it programatically.

Comment: Although you said it may be rejected, I'd like to stress point that it is a private API and the use of such is prohibited by Apple. Thus, would strongly recommend not to do it in a production app. Anyway, I will leave the question in case it'll change or someone will think of a workaround. Thank you for your answer.